# Iterating to move files in python

Tags: python, iterator, shutil

I'm having trouble with a complicated move.  I have a dataframe of picture locations, and destination locations.  I have a 'train/test/val' directory.  Currently, all files are within the train directory and within another folder according to their class (28 classes in all).

I need to move 10% of each class from the train/class directory to the test/class directory and val/class directory leaving 80% of the files where they are at.

I used the following code to move all files into their class folders from one solid folder:

```
import shutil
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for index, row in labels.iterrows():
        try:
            shutil.move(row['location'], row['destination'])
        except:
            pass
```

I'm running up against a wall figuring out how to move a certain number of files according to their class.

The below is a dataframe of each class, the number of files in column `count` an the number of files to move to the test directory and validation directory in `move_count`.

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'class': ['other_hazard', 'roof', 'front_of_dwelling',
       'address_verification', 'rear_of_dwelling',
       'left_front_of_dwelling', 'right_front_of_dwelling',
       'detached_structure', 'roof_hazard', 'right_side_of_dwelling',
       'left_side_of_dwelling', 'other', 'left_rear_of_dwelling',
       'right_rear_of_dwelling', 'restricted_access', 'opportunity_line',
       'dog_on_premises', 'pool', 'adjacent_exposure', 'apparent_feature',
       'basement', 'hot_tub', 'utl_utc',
       'supplemental_heating_source_(wood_stove)', 'brush',
       'electrical_panel', 'street_sign_(utl)', 'business_exposure'], 'count': [643612, 631651, 441595, 436153, 365357, 275534, 275023, 220917,
       194744, 110098, 109182,  59484,  46058,  45358,  21599,  13753,
         5668,   4586,   3292,   3197,   2899,   2873,   2862,   1994,
         1677,   1392,   1077,   1063], 'move_count': [64361., 63165., 44160., 43615., 36536., 27553., 27502., 22092.,
       19474., 11010., 10918.,  5948.,  4606.,  4536.,  2160.,  1375.,
         567.,   459.,   329.,   320.,   290.,   287.,   286.,   199.,
         168.,   139.,   108.,   106.]}

df_class = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

The below is a sample of of the dataframe that lists where the files are at, and where I need to move the percentage of files to.

```
 df = {'PictureFilename': ['0091240758-91931712.JPG','0091240791-91646592.JPG', '0091240791-91646593.JPG']
      , 'Target': ['Detached Structure','Address Verification', 'Other']
      , 'location': ['D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\train\\0091240758-91931712.JPG'
                     ,'D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\train\\0091240791-91646592.JPG'
                     ,'D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\train\\0091240791-91646593.JPG']
      ,'test_move_location' : ['D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\test\detached_structure'
                               ,'D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\test\\address_verification'
                               ,'D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\test\\other']
      , 'val_move_location': ['D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\val\\detached_structure'
                               ,'D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\val\\address+verification'
                               ,'D:\\CIS inspection images 0318\\Photos\\val\\other']
     }

df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
```

I'm having trouble using one DF to guide the other and execute this move.  Any suggestions?  This what i've tried with just a print statement to start and it seems to get hung up.  I'm not even sure if it's keeping the right count with the right class:

```
for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    for i, r in df_class.iterrows():
        if row['target'] == r['class']:
            for i in range(1, r['move_count']):
                print(i, row['target'], r['class'])
```

Ok, I've found a way to iterate through the dataframe and print the location and destination of the files which means I can move them.  I have not been able to figure out how to to stop the movement at a certain number of files.

```
categories = df_class['class'].unique()

for category in categories:
    n = 0
    for index, row in labels.iterrows():
        if category == row['target']:
            n += 1
            print(n, train_dir+'\\'+row['target']+'\\'+row['PictureFilename'], 'destination: '+ test_dir+'\\'+row['target']+'\\'+row['PictureFilename'])
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Nothing.  It just hangs up and I have to stop the kernel.  I'm not even sure if I'm calculating the right counts of files for each class (contained in `df_class`.

Comment: avoid bare try/except. Print exceptions when you encounter them. Also print the current file being moved. That helps figuring it out

Comment: Thank you.  I can't even get the print to work however.  I'm not sure i'm iterrating through both dataframes properly and I'm not sure the iterrable is calculating each class' amount to move.  I'm looking for an iterable that says, this file belongs to this class and is the 15 file to move, this file is that class and is the 63,000 file to move, only x amount of files to move.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trying, I figured out the answer.  Well, a answer. There is probably something more efficient.

```
#move 10% to test folder
for i, r in label_move_count.iterrows():
    n=0
    for index, row in labels.iterrows():
        if row['target'] == r['target']:
            #n+=1
            if n < row['testcount']:
                try:
                    shutil.move(row['destination']+'\\'+row['PictureFilename'], row['test_destination'])
                    print(n, row['target'])
                    n+=1
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            pass
```

I ran this twice to move 10% to the validation folder as well.